# « S’autoincriminer », « se rendre coupable », « se défendre de présumés»?

Tags: formulation-idiomatique, formulation, constructions, reformulation

À force de me demander si je vais bien, malgré que je lui dise que tout va bien et cela en cherchant à retourner la situation en sa faveur, n’est-elle pas en train

…de s’autoincriminer?

…de se rendre coupable, à ses dépens, de torts qu’elle aurait pu me faire.

…de chercher à se défendre de présumés torts qu’elle aurait pu me faire et cela à son corps défendant.

-/-/-/

…de se mettre les pieds dans le plat en avouant, à son corps défendant, un mauvais traitement qu’elle aurait pu me réserver.

Je cherche d’autres façons qui s’inscrivent dans cet esprit de formuler cette idée.

Contexte:

Les personne concernée se sait coupable (elle me réserve un mauvais traitement depuis un moment) , mais elle cherche à retourner la situation en faisant l’innocente.

Comment: On « cherche **en** faire qqc » et on « **se** met les  pieds  dans le plat » au  Canada  ?

Comment: Disons que j’ai quelque peu brutaliser la langue française…

Comment: Et tu continues ;-)

Comment: Oups…brutalisé**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> À force de me demander sans cesse si je vais bien et d'ignorer mes réponses positives qui pourtant vont en sa faveur, n'est-elle pas en train de se tirer une balle dans le pied en révélant qu'elle se sent en réalité coupable de mauvais traitement à mon égard.

Comment: Ça répond tout à fait à mes attentes! Merci jlliagre.

Answer (score 0):

J'aime bien "auto-incriminer", ou sinon :

> ne se désigne-t-elle pas elle-même comme coupable de torts...

> ne se démasque-t-elle pas elle-même comme coupable de torts...

> n'est-elle pas en train de se dévoiler elle-même comme coupable de torts...

> ne se rend-elle pas elle-même soupçonnable de torts... *(moins fort)*

Comment: C’est bien la variété! Ce sont des tournures que je vais rajouter dans mon répertoire très limité de tournures. Merci guillaume31